# UK immigration check at airport

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, passports, visas-on-arrival

I always wonder that what UK immigration at airport check in their computer and why they type our answers in their PC?

Answer (score 3):

For the first part of your question "what UK Immigration...check in their computer"...

> Immigration Officers at the border are obliged to examine all
>   passports at ports of entry and to check them against the records
>   stored upon our database; this is   accomplished by means of the
>   scanning process you have observed. I can confirm,  however, that the
>   system employed for the scanning procedure has a read-only capability
>   and does not record any details from documents which are scanned.
>
> It is necessary at times to hold details of individuals in order to
>   maintain the integrity  of our borders and the general security of the
>   United Kingdom.  Such information will  come from different sources
>   and is regularly monitored, updated and removed from database records
>   when deemed appropriate. I hope you will understand that, for  reasons
>   both of confidentiality and security, I am not at liberty to discuss
>   the nature of any information held on our database, nor discuss the
>   sources from which such information originates.

Source: [Information held from Passport Scans](https://www.whatdotheyknow.com/request/information_held_from_passport_s)

The scan at the Immigration Officer's station is very rudimentary.  They check their database to see if there is any matches for your passport or biometrics.  If there is a match, the computer will return a stop/detain indicator.  The passport scan also returns all of the basic information from your passport to help them detect forgery.  If there is a stop/detain or something else where they need to check further, they will take the passport to a secured station where more detailed information is returned.  That's why they sometimes disappear for a moment.

Also, if you have an [entry clearance](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/what-is-entry-clearance-ecb03/ecb3-what-is-entry-clearance) (visa) in your passport, the system will verify that it was properly issued and has not been cancelled.  They may also want to pull up the full [Proviso](http://www.statewatch.org/news/2002/apr/02ukvisa.htm) record and if so they will take it to a secured station for that reason.

For the second part of your question: "why are they entering your responses in to the computer".  They do this in order to have a record of the interview.  They may also enter the number on your [landing card](https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control/at-border-control) (the white card you filled out before landing) in case they need to find it again.