# Travel to England from Argentina: how much money for a 17 day visit?

Tags: uk, budget, visas-on-arrival, argentina, proof-of-funds

How much money would I need to bring with me if I want to enter the United Kingdom from Argentina, is there a minimum for 17 days or will they ask me to show my finances ?

Comment: I take it you're an Argentinian citizen? What visa are you applying for? Have you looked at the requirements for the visa on the British govt websites?

Comment: no i am English i am asking for my GF she is Argentinian ,that is great thank you so much .We found out that she doesn't need a visa .

Comment: We had been told you have to have a certain amount of money to get into the country and the amount we have been told was pretty high that's why i  checked out various websites etc  and have a good idea now .Thank you and good night from the UK  :)

Comment: @Peter, if your gf plays it straight up with the IO, she's then off the hook for accommodation and maintenance.  That changes the topology of your question in a fairly radical way.

Answer (score 3):

If you are travelling on an Argentina passport, you will be able to apply for leave to enter at a UK port.  The applicable rules for this case are found in [Immigration Rules for visitors](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423477/20150424_mmigration_rules_app_v_final_v2.pdf) which has this to say about funds...

> (the applicant) must have sufficient funds to cover all reasonable costs in relation
>   to their visit without working or accessing public funds. This
>   includes the cost of the return or onward journey, any costs relating
>   to dependants, and the cost of planned activities such as private
>   medical treatment.

So there is no fixed amount of cash specified for a given visit and no specified per diem amount.  During the landing interview the Immigration Officer may ask for evidence of financial capacity and they are entitled to refuse entry if they are not satisfied.

In order to help visitors prepare for their landing interview, they publish [guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423699/2015_04_20_Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_Final__2__-_CLEAN.pdf), which has this to say about financial evidence...

> Financial documents showing that you have sufficient funds available.
>   These must clearly show that you have access to the funds, such as:
>
> - bank statements
> - building society book
> - proof of earnings such as a letter from employer confirming    employment details (start date of employment, salary, role, company
>     contact details)
> - where a third party (who is either in the UK or who will be legally    in the UK at the time of your visit) is providing financial support
>     to you e.g. a business, a friend or a relative, documents to show
>     they have sufficient resources to support you in addition to
>     themselves and any dependant family should be provided

Having said all of that, the answers to your questions are...

**is there a minimum for 17 days?**, no. per the rules there is no minimum amount.

**will they ask me to show my finances?**, probably yes, especially if it is your first visit or your demographic profile (age, gender, apparent lifestyle, etc) triggers a more intrusive line of questioning.  Successful applicants generally bring recent bank statements (3 months) in their name, and their employment contract and an employer's confirmation.  If you have a mortgage statement, it can also be helpful.

So much for the rules.  You tagged your question with 'budget', which indicates you are also interested in a benchmark to use for planning.  You mentioned 'England' and the budget needs for England are wildly divergent depending upon which region you want to visit.  Central London/Westminster are the most expensive and it's practical to think in terms of GBP 60 - GBP 125 per day over and above the accommodation (hotel, B&B, social arrangements, etc).  However those numbers, or any other concrete numbers, invite debate because they are **derived from opinion**.

See also:  [How much money do I need to show as proof of support when applying for a UK Standard Visitor visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42529/how-much-money-do-i-need-to-show-as-proof-of-support-when-applying-for-a-uk-tour)

See also:  [UK Immigration officers arrivals interview questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49231/will-be-heading-to-the-uk-soon-what-will-be-asked-by-the-uk-immigration-office)

See also: [UK immigration check at airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46830/uk-immigration-check-at-airport)

See also: [Refused entry to UK, not sure what to do](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47180/refused-entry-to-uk-not-sure-what-to-do)

Comment: @pnuts, nice point.  Edited.

Comment: @Peter, please don't thank, it's ok.  Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @pnuts, I totally promise there are no 'secrets'.  Meet up in chat if you like to discuss :)